# Spark performance: local faster than cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to setup a Spark Cluster on my home network and I'm not seeing any performance gain compared to standalone - in fact its slightly slower compared to when I run against local[*].  Can someone please help / explain why?

What I did as follows:

- I am using the MovieLens 10M Dataset. http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-10m.zip
- For my local cluster I have two modern high performance macs with the same spec and 32 GB RAM each
- When I run standalone Spark instance only ie local[*] my time is 30.82 minutes
- When I run against a spark cluster connecting the two macs into the same spark cluster my time is 35 minutes

My spark-submit parameters for the spark cluster is as follows

```
spark-submit --class com.sundogsoftware.spark.MovieSimilarities10MDataset --deploy-mode cluster --master spark://mbp2.lan:7077  --driver-memory 1g
--num-executors 2 --executor-cores 8 --executor-memory 28g
```

This results in 8 cores being used on each mac and 28GB RAM used (confirmed this via the spark webapp)

Naturally I am expecting that given two identical machines in hardware spec and connecting them to the same spark cluster, I'd see the performance improve using the same dataset (MovieLens 10M)

Would appreciate any advice.  I've tweaked the number of executors / cores / memory a number of times and that's having no impact.

Thx

Class is below:

```
package com.sundogsoftware.spark

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import org.apache.log4j._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, LongType, StringType, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}

// To run on EMR successfully + output results for Star Wars:
// aws s3 cp s3://sundog-spark/MovieSimilarities1MDataset.jar ./
// aws s3 cp s3://sundog-spark/ml-10M100K/movies.dat ./
// spark-submit --executor-memory 1g MovieSimilarities1MDataset.jar 260

object MovieSimilarities10MDataset {

  case class Movies(userID: Int, movieID: Int, rating: Int, timestamp: Long)
  case class MoviesNames(movieID: Int, movieTitle: String)
  case class MoviePairs(movie1: Int, movie2: Int, rating1: Int, rating2: Int)
  case class MoviePairsSimilarity(movie1: Int, movie2: Int, score: Double, numPairs: Long)

  def computeCosineSimilarity(spark: SparkSession, data: Dataset[MoviePairs]): Dataset[MoviePairsSimilarity] = {
    // Compute xx, xy and yy columns
    val pairScores = data
      .withColumn("xx", col("rating1") * col("rating1"))
      .withColumn("yy", col("rating2") * col("rating2"))
      .withColumn("xy", col("rating1") * col("rating2"))

    // Compute numerator, denominator and numPairs columns
    val calculateSimilarity = pairScores
      .groupBy("movie1", "movie2")
      .agg(
        sum(col("xy")).alias("numerator"),
        (sqrt(sum(col("xx"))) * sqrt(sum(col("yy")))).alias("denominator"),
        count(col("xy")).alias("numPairs")
      )

    // Calculate score and select only needed columns (movie1, movie2, score, numPairs)
    import spark.implicits._
    val result = calculateSimilarity
      .withColumn("score",
        when(col("denominator") =!= 0, col("numerator") / col("denominator"))
          .otherwise(null)
      ).select("movie1", "movie2", "score", "numPairs").as[MoviePairsSimilarity]

    result
  }

  /** Get movie name by given movie id */
  def getMovieName(movieNames: Dataset[MoviesNames], movieId: Int): String = {
    val result = movieNames.filter(col("movieID") === movieId)
      .select("movieTitle").collect()(0)

    result(0).toString
  }
  /** Our main function where the action happens */
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // Set the log level to only print errors
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val startTime = System.nanoTime

    // Create a SparkSession without specifying master
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("MovieSimilarities10M")
      .getOrCreate()

    // Create schema when reading u.item
    val moviesNamesSchema = new StructType()
      .add("movieID", IntegerType, nullable = true)
      .add("movieTitle", StringType, nullable = true)

    // Create schema when reading u.data
    val moviesSchema = new StructType()
      .add("userID", IntegerType, nullable = true)
      .add("movieID", IntegerType, nullable = true)
      .add("rating", IntegerType, nullable = true)
      .add("timestamp", LongType, nullable = true)

    println("\nLoading movie names...")
    import spark.implicits._
    // Create a broadcast dataset of movieID and movieTitle.
    // Apply ISO-885901 charset
    val movieNames = spark.read
      .option("sep", "::")
      .option("charset", "ISO-8859-1")
      .schema(moviesNamesSchema)
      .csv("movies.dat")
      .as[MoviesNames]

    // Load up movie data as dataset
    val movies = spark.read
      .option("sep", "::")
      .schema(moviesSchema)
      .csv("ratings.dat")
      .as[Movies]

    val ratings = movies.select("userId", "movieId", "rating")

    // Emit every movie rated together by the same user.
    // Self-join to find every combination.
    // Select movie pairs and rating pairs
    val moviePairs = ratings.as("ratings1")
      .join(ratings.as("ratings2"), $"ratings1.userId" === $"ratings2.userId" && $"ratings1.movieId" < $"ratings2.movieId")
      .select($"ratings1.movieId".alias("movie1"),
        $"ratings2.movieId".alias("movie2"),
        $"ratings1.rating".alias("rating1"),
        $"ratings2.rating".alias("rating2")
      ).repartition(100).as[MoviePairs]

    val moviePairSimilarities = computeCosineSimilarity(spark, moviePairs).cache()

    if (args.length > 0) {
      val scoreThreshold = 0.88
      val coOccurenceThreshold = 1000.0

      val movieID: Int = args(0).toInt

      // Filter for movies with this sim that are "good" as defined by
      // our quality thresholds above
      val filteredResults = moviePairSimilarities.filter(
        (col("movie1") === movieID || col("movie2") === movieID) &&
          col("score") > scoreThreshold && col("numPairs") > coOccurenceThreshold)

      // Sort by quality score.
      val results = filteredResults.sort(col("score").desc).take(50)

      println("\nTop 50 similar movies for " + getMovieName(movieNames, movieID))
      for (result <- results) {
        // Display the similarity result that isn't the movie we're looking at
        var similarMovieID = result.movie1
        if (similarMovieID == movieID) {
          similarMovieID = result.movie2
        }
        println(getMovieName(movieNames, similarMovieID) + "\tscore: " + result.score + "\tstrength: " + result.numPairs)
      }

      val stopTime = System.nanoTime
      val elapsedTime = (stopTime - startTime)


      // TimeUnit
      val convert = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(elapsedTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)

      //    System.out.println(convert + " seconds")
      println(s"elapsedTime sec=$convert")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you try with more executors but less core/memory by executor ?
like : --num-executors 5 , --executor-cores 3, --executor-memory 10g

Comment: Thx, running this now ie --driver-memory 2g --num-executors 5 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 10g

Comment: Unfortunately no change in the finish time on the cluster; still 35 min.  thx

Comment: cluster will only be faster for you if the calculation stage is more expensive than loading, deserialising and shuffling the two input files which I'm assuming are a single partition each? In your case these would be the  multiplications and the new columns. Since loading and collecting is all constraint to use a few execs at once or the driver. Measuring the time of each big block of logic would help you see where the bottleneck is

Answer (score 0):

You're downloading the same dataset twice off the internet instead of once. This takes longer than downloading it once.

As a side note, you're doing numerical processing here. You'd probably get way more speedup using a GPU and doing this as a bulk matrix operation on a gpu.

Comment: Thanks the file is local and is not being downloaded.  I've removed the comment so that's not confusing re: the S3 reference.  that was a code comment from the example (this is course code) not mine

Comment: You've pre-provisioned it on each node? It's almost certainly that your join is causing a shuffle across the network.

Comment: Yes, pre-provisioned on each node.  It's a local network though.  any tips on how I can see this? thx

Comment: Look at the spark console. You'll see the execution plan, time spent shuffling, data spent in shuffle, etc. Also `$"ratings1.movieId" < $"ratings2.movieId"` is way more expensive than an equijoin. It's not obvious to me why you need that,.

Comment: Thanks will look.  It’s not my code it’s from a Udemy course and I am only trying to compare apples to apples (standalone spark vs cluster) with all other inputs the same

Comment: There's a lot of overhead from distributed spark you don't get in standalone: the communications, the need to marshall data over the wire etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

- There's a lot of overhead from distributed spark you don't get in standalone: the communications, the need to marshall data over the wire etc etc. I think you'd need more than two workers before moving off standalone is justified.
- Make sure the data is in a form which can be easily split across the workers. Consider making step one of your workflow loading the .dat file and saving it in Parquet, or at least avro format, maybe compressed with snappy (but not gzip).

You are going to need a shared filesystem for everything to work; for two machines NFS is the one you are using, correct? Stick the (converted) source files in exactly the same path on the local FS, and use the shared NFS for all other work. That way: no network IO to load the data.